# On startup login sometimes do not work (It is frozen.) on Kubuntu

Tags: boot, login

As topic says. Sometimes when i boot up the PC the login is frozen
So i ll have to restart the PC and then it works as usual.
I am running the latest version of Kubuntu = 23.10
Is there a fix to this?